# IOS Swift: How to change text color and font of menu items using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController class to implement side-out slide bar. I followed [this](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) link and side bar is coming.

But I want to change the text colour and size of item texts of slide bar. Any idea how to do it?

[image]

I couldn't find any way to update it. Though there are parameters to update the size of window (_initDefaultProperties) but not the item text.

Comment: Select the label in prototype cell and change the color.

Comment: :)....You are right. I didn't notice that. such a small thing. Thanks anyway